# PHP Results to AJAX for comparison array issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Having a bit of an issue here with PHP and AJAX. Hopefully someone can help me out:

Goal:

Compare dates from a database with dates acquired from an each loop in jquery using Ajax

What I have so far:

**Ajax/jQuery:**

```
var $sqlcal = $('#calHeader').data('sqlcal');//contains database

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'XXXX.php',
        data: {sqlcal: $sqlcal},
        success: function(data){

            var x = data;

            $('.open-button').each(function(){
                var e = $(this);
                var e1 = e.data('dtc'); //contains dates yyyy-mm-dd

                if (e1 == x){
                    //e.css('background','red');
                    console.log('yes')
                }else{
                    console.log('no');
                    }
                //console.log(e1);
            });

        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('didnt work');
        }

    });
```

**PHP**

```
//MySQL Database Connect
include 'scripts/connect.php';



if(isset($_GET['sqlcal'])){

$currentCal = $_GET['sqlcal'];
$sqlGetEvents = "SELECT eventDate FROM $currentCal";
$eventResults = $connection->query($sqlGetEvents);

if ($eventResults->num_rows > 0){
    $a = array();
    while($row = $eventResults->fetch_array()){
        array_push($a, array($row['eventDate']));
    }
     echo (json_encode($a));
  }
}//end of script
```

**PHP Results Format:**

```
[
    ["2016-02-05"],
    ["2016-02-05"],
    ["2016-02-05"],
    ["2016-02-06"],
    ["2016-02-07"]
]
```

I cannot seem to get the array in a format that I can use to compare with the jQuery information. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Which format is returned from your  DB?

Comment: Thanks for responding, i have updated my question to reflect that information. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: `if (e1 == x){` seems wrong. `x` is the data returned by PHP (an array), and you said `e1` is the dates (an array). You can't just compare two arrays with `==`. Even if `e1` was a string, `x` is still an array right?

Comment: Try `console.log(data)` just after success callback and show us the result please.

Comment: @chan - im using jquery each to loop through all the elements that have the '.open-button' class(all the dates in a calender). The e1 gathers the elements 'data-dtc'(full date in yyyy-mm-dd). My thinking was that jQuery will compare the e1 value to x(array) and if it equals, change the background to red for each matching selector. Obviously this is not working so im wrong but thats what I wanted to accomplished.

Comment: @zakaria - getting the same output as above

[["2016-02-05"],["2016-02-05"],["2016-02-05"],["2016-02-06"],["2016-02-07"]]

Comment: maybe you can use jQuerys `.inArray()` method : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: @codeGodie - Definitely tried that but Im afraid that im not using it correctly. When I do:

"jQuery.inArray(e1, x) "

I get 29 yes in console.log (there should only be 3)

Comment: wait why are making them be an array of arrays? `array_push($a, array($row['eventDate']));` why not just regular arrays: `array_push($a,$row['eventDate']);` ?

Comment: if you were to make the result set a one dimensional array, using `.inArray(e1, x)` would work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103986/discussion-between-user247326-and-codegodie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `.inArray` and you your PHP should only output one dimensional array like : `["2016-02-04", "2016-02-05", "2016-02-05", "2016-02-06", "2016-02-07"]`. Also, if you are receiving JSON, make sure to set your `dataType` to `'json'`. In other words your code should be:

**PHP:**

```
while($row = $eventResults->fetch_array()){
    array_push($a, $row['eventDate']);
}
```

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'data.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (dates) {

        $('.open-button').each(function () {
            var date = $(this).data('dtc'); //contains dates yyyy-mm-dd
            if ($.inArray(date, dates) > -1) {
                $(this).css('color', 'red');
                console.log('yes')
            } else {
                console.log('no');
            }
        });

    },
    error: function () {
        console.log('didnt work');
    }

});
```

Comment: that works! So the question is...why doesnt this work with the returned data from php?

Comment: Wrong format because youre using json_encode and that turns it into string, unless specified in your ajax request, do this: `dataType: 'json',` i will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem come from the date fromat returned from your DB, try to convert the returned dates to the date you have in your jQuery code :

```
while($row = $eventResults->fetch()){
    $date = date("yyyy-mm-dd", strtotime($row['eventDate']));
    array_push($a, array($date));
}
```

**After your edit:**

`x` is an array of arrays so you cant just do `if (e1 == x){` you should get the value from each item, try :

```
$('.open-button').each(function( index ){
    var e = $(this);
    var e1 = e.data('dtc'); //contains dates yyyy-mm-dd

    if (e1 == x[index]){
        console.log('yes')
    }else{
        console.log('no');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.